# GET server informations

Tags: php

I'm new to web development and I'm always thrilled about what can be done.
Some days ago testing an account with Zopim I remain impressed about a function they have called connection quality, the popup is full of useful informations such connection quality, progress, session uptime, latency, server local time etc. I post a picture to be clear.
[image]
My questions are:

- Is safe to display such informations to the end user?
- I'm learning PHP, could PHP do a same thing, or this informations are retrieved by something more near to the OS? If so I would like to know more to study and begin testing some code locally.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes its safe. it will show your user about connection in advance.

i dont think so if PHP can do it, and its look like near OS, maybe you need to mix PHP with other programming language such as Perl or Python. commonly used in server programming.

Answer (score 0):

Put the user first in the first question and it becomes: *Is this of any interest to the end user?*
I hope you can decide yourself that the answer to my question is **No**.

Regarding the second question, `PHP` is just a programming language. It manipulates data. The data have to be provided by some source. 
`PHP` can be used in several ways to collect data from various sources and process it.

A possible source of information for some of the data displayed above is the OS itself. Another source can be a monitoring software that provides an API to the clients for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it is safe.
But, To connect HTTP request, HTTP header is necessary.
we can get these infomation By using PHP server method.
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php
we also get the infomation(user agent etc...) near to the OS.